# How to plot the product of the NDSolve result and any known function

Tags: plotting

How can I plot the product of the `NDSolve` result, e.g. `x[t]/.solution` and any known function, for instance, `Sin[x]`?

Answer (score 4):

In the examples you find:

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. s], {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Expand it like this for the product with Sin[t]:

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. s] * Sin[t], {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you meant `Sin[x]`, then I suppose something like

```
 Plot[Evaluate[Sin[x[t]] /. solution], {t, 0, 20}]
```

is what you're after.  In this case, the term "product" should be read as "composition."

If, on the other hand, you meant to multiply the solution by `Sin[t]`, then perhaps

```
Plot[Evaluate[Sin[t] x[t] /. solution], {t, 0, 20}]
```

will do.  (`Evaluate` has to be the [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Head.html) of the argument for it to override the [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html) attribute of `Plot`.)